# Remove what chrome claims is padding

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/k8s4j/6/

Given the fiddle above, I am stuck... In Chrome it claims that the bottom elements have allot of padding somehow, but I can't seem to identify where it originates from.

In any case, I need "HIGH" to be placed inside the box.

Please view this in Chrome btw, because it is meant for a Chrome plugin, so other browsers won't make sense atm.

There is properly some superfluous padding and margin declarations in the CSS... I basically just tried adding explicit margin and padding all over to see if I couldn't find the sinner.

Comment: I'm not seeing any padding on elements in the bottom row, in Chrome 21/Win XP. Corrected: the `.footer .hours` has 4px padding on the left and right; but that's the only one I could see. Which element(s) are troubling you?

Comment: When you use the "Dev tools" it colors the area that is not meant to be there "green", when you look in the metrics box that is denounced as padding...

It does not calculate any unwanted padding on elements... Should properly have "cleared" that i meant "padding" from what the metrics indicator said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.priorityheader_priority` has `display: table-cell;`, you need to also give it `vertical-align: top;` for the desired alignment.

Comment: Also, wrapping both divs in the footer with a div that has display:table-row would be logical, but won't change the display.

Comment: All "display: table-cell;" elements needed that to "Almost" fix it up... I understand what vertical-aling top does, and that if you have a "to big cell" where you wan't an element on the top you need it... But where does it get it's height from here?... I mean the layout wouln't really care if those elements was valigned buttom, middle or top.

Comment: It's coming from your `.hours span` elements with `display: inline-block`. Every time you use `display` with `table-cell` or `inline-block`, consider adding `vertical-align: top`. Particularly if things are looking strange. The default of `vertical-align: baseline` is often not what you want.

Comment: +1 for your answer was working on demo and you gave a answer and even got accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hear is the working [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ogijud/3/edit)

just change the following **CSS:**

```
        .priorityheader_priority {
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align:top;
            width: 112px;
            padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
        .priority {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 25px;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: block;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 120%;
            padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
```